# Building QString out string

Tags: c++, string, qt, qstring

With the following piece of code:

```
QString msg;
msg =   "Datalogging Item"          + ',' +
        QString::number(item)       + ',' +
        "Slave Index"               + ',' +
        QString::number(slaveIndex) + ',' +
        "Slave Name"                + ',' +
        slaveName                   + ',' +
        "Experiment Index"          + ',' +
        QString::number(expIndex)   + ',' +
        "Experiment Name"           + ',' +
        expName                     + ',' +
        "Aquisition Frequency "     + ',' +
        "33 Hz"                     + "\n";
qDebug() << msg;
```

I was getting the following debug output

```
"riment Index0,Slave Index,0,Slave Name,Execute 1,Experiment Index,0,Experiment Name,Read All (Barebone),Aquisition Frequency ,33 Hz\n"
```

Wich is not really what I was expected to get.

But with the code modified with the QString typecast:

```
QString msg;
msg =   QString("Datalogging Item")     + QString(',') +
        QString::number(item)           + QString(',') +
        QString("Slave Index")          + QString(',') +
        QString::number(slaveIndex)     + QString(',') +
        QString("Slave Name")           + QString(',') +
        slaveName                       + QString(',') +
        QString("Experiment Index")     + QString(',') +
        QString::number(expIndex)       + QString(',') +
        QString("Experiment Name")      + QString(',') +
        expName                         + QString(',') +
        QString("Aquisition Frequency ")+ QString(',') +
        QString("33 Hz")                + QString("\n");
qDebug() << msg;
```

I get what I expected to get:

```
"Datalogging Item,0,Slave Index,0,Slave Name,Execute 1,Experiment Index,0,Experiment Name,Read All (Barebone),Aquisition Frequency ,33 Hz\n"
```

Do you have any clue on what is going on? I just don't get what is going on and I'm a newbie to QT.

Thanks.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, please add the expected behaviour and the current behaviour in a clear cut manner to your question description.

Comment: He's asking why the first example code is printing garbage characters in the output.  Which I attempt to answer below.

Comment: You may want to use QString::arg() instead. That is what I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression

```
"Datalogging Item" + ','
```

has the type and meaning of

```
static_cast<const char *>("Datalogging Item" + 44)
```

You're taking the address of the beginning of the `Datalogging` string constant and adding 44 to it - advancing it by 44 characters. This is undefined behavior as you're moving a pointer past the object it points to. By coincidence the pointer happens to point to another C string constant.

A short program that reproduces the issue:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  std::cout << "Datalogging Item Foo Bar Baz" + '\n' << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
g Item Foo Bar Baz
```

One way of rewriting your expression to make it valid and less verbose would be to use the arg-substitution mechanism of `QString`:

```
auto msg = QStringLiteral(
  "Datalogging Item,%1,Slave Index,%2,Slave Name,%3,Experiment Index,%4,"
  "Experiment Name,%5,Acquisition Frequency,%6\n")
   .arg(item).arg(slaveIndex).arg(slaveName).arg(expIndex)
   .arg(expName).arg(QStringLiteral("33 Hz"));
```

If you're using Qt 4, replace `QStringLiteral` with `QString::fromUtf8`. The `QStringLiteral` is a mechanism introduced in Qt 5 that builds up a constant `QString` instance at compile time, yielding smaller code and better runtime performance than the use of a `QString` constructor.

Comment: Thanks. I get it now. You answer was helpful!

Answer (score 3):

You can repro similar results even simpler:

```
 msg =   "Datalogging Item" + ',' +  QString::number(item);
```

And now it occurs to be exactly what the issue is.  The first part of that expression is simply:

```
"Datalogging Item" + ','
```

In the above expression, a raw string literal is having the integer value of 44 (ascii val for comma) added to it's pointer address. Hence, you are now in "undefined" territory since the length of `"Datalogging Item"` is far less than 44 characters. Most likely what's happening is that the above expression is now a pointer expression into the middle of one of your other string literals defined nearby.

The solution is simply to declare the **first** element to be a QString so that all subsequent "additions" will use the overloaded `+` operator of QString:

```
msg =   QString("Datalogging Item") + ',' +
        QString::number(item)       + ',' +
        ...
```

Comment: All you need to reproduce is `std::cout << "Datalogging Item" + ','` :) No need for Qt. Or also `printf("%s\n", "Datalogging Item" + ',');`. No need for C++ :)

Comment: Your answer was helpful too!

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use QStringLiteral macro for static string in code.

```
msg = QStringLiteral("Datalogging Item") + ',' +
```

More info here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#QStringLiteral